# Python: How to access Instance Variables from another Class?

Tags: python

Conceptually: I want to access an instance variable defined in a certain class from some other class

My Case: I want to access the self.x instance variable defined in the Human Class from my Alien class

Why?: I am creating a space-invaders game where there are 2 spaceships (human class), and the aliens are '*raining down*', the goal is to dodge those aliens. I will have 2 objects for the human classes corresponding to the 2 ships. In my alien class there is a section where it detects whether or not it is in the collision zone of any of the 2 spaceships (second block of code). So basically since the 'self.x' variable is an instance variable for each ship, if I could somehow access it in my alien class then any Alien object would be able to detect collision for either the spaceships (since self.x represents the x-coordinates of each spaceship).

```
class Human:

    y = display_height * 0.8
    width = 120
    x_change = 0

    def __init__(self, image, initpos, left, right):
        self.image = image
        self.x = display_width * initpos
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def run(self):
        global gameExit
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == self.left:
                    if self.x > 0:
                        self.x_change = -8
                    else:
                        self.x_change = 0
                elif event.key == self.right:
                    if self.x < display_width - Human.width:
                        self.x_change = 8
                    else:
                        self.x_change = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == self.left or event.key == self.right:
                        self.x_change = 0
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x, Human.y))
        self.x += self.x_change

human1 = Human(pygame.image.load('human.png'), 0.5, pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT)
human2 = Human(pygame.image.load('human2.png'), 0.3, pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d)

class Alien:

    height = 120
    width = 80
    x = random.randrange(width, (display_width - width))
    y = -100

    def __init__(self, image, speed, hp):
        self.image = image
        self.speed = speed
        self.hp = hp

    def run(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.y += self.speed

    def checkpos(self):
        global points
        if self.y > display_height:
            self.y = 0 - Alien.height
            self.x = random.randrange(Alien.width, display_width - Alien.width)
            points += 1
```

> so this is where the issue starts basically Human.y works fine since y is a class variable, it remains static as the human ship only changes in the horizontal axis. But x is an instance variable for Human: and I can't make it a class variable because ill need to do a multiplayer mode where there will be 2 ships so each human object has to be controlled separately. So I need to somehow access the instant variable self.x from the Human: class in my following if statement which is in the alien class

```
        if Human.y < self.y + Alien.height:
            print("y cross alien")
            if self.x < ("need to access instance variable self.x FROM HUMAN class") < self.x + Alien.width or self.x < ("same issue") + Human.width < self.x + Alien.width:
                print("x cross alien")

alien1 = Alien(pygame.image.load('alien1.png'), 7, 3)
alien2 = Alien(pygame.image.load('alien2.png'), 8, 4)
alien3 = Alien(pygame.image.load('alien3.png'), 9, 5)
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you written any code?

Comment: Please show your code. Have you made any instances of either class?

Comment: yep guys ive updated the code thanks for those instant replies really loving the community

Comment: You want to compare the `x` of a human object (i.e. `human1.x`) and not of the entire class: `def checkpos(self, human): if (self.x-human.x)**2<2: pass` and then call this for all pairs `alien1.checkpos(human1)` ...
You can - for now - not call `Human.x` but only `human1.x` for any created `Human` called `human1`

Comment: @Snowbunting I dont want to compare it to a single object. I want it hardcoded into the class of the alien. Because ill have multiple aliens and therefore multiple objects, and so I want it so that if any one of those aliens collides it executes the print('crossover'). You get me?

Comment: Sure, but the way to do that is to loop over all possible combinations (human, alien) and check the collision for each such pair.

Comment: @Snowbunting but thats what I want to avoid. Basically I want it as a behaviour of all aliens when they get into collision range that they execute the print('crossover'). Hence why I want to make it a part of the class aliens: I want it as part of their behaviour, so that any alien object I create will automatically have that collision system ready

Comment: if there was just someway I can access the instance variable (self.x) of the human class, then I could make any alien object I create interact with the spaceship sprite and execute the crossover print when they collide

Comment: you can see it will work fine with the y crossover, since there is no 'self.y" for the human class, as y is a static class variable. Thus I can call It from my alien: class just by typing Human.y without problems. I want to mirror the same process just with the humans x coordinate which is an instance variable namely (self.x).

Comment: The logic problem here is: Assume you have two humans h1 and h2, what would you expect `Human.x` to be? `h1.x`? `h2.x`? or a list containing both? Do you see that?

Comment: The simplest way is: 1) Make a list containing all your humans. 2) make a method `Alien.checkpos` that takes either one human or a list of all humans. 3) In your game's update function call `alien.checkpos` for each alien.

Comment: @Snowbunting I would expect it to be the same value as the self.x in the Human: class, I just want to transfer the value across to the alien class

Comment: @Snowbunting yep thanks I see what you mean. But this is a very general question, I mean there must be a way in which u can access an instance variable defined in some class from another class. In my case, I just want to get the self.x value of the Human class and use that variable in my Alien class. I mean there must be some way to do this right?

Comment: Maybe you should google the difference of classes and objects... you see that `human1.x` and `human2.x` will not necessairly be the same value? They are the same at the beginning, but might deviate later so `Human.x` does not even exist.

Comment: @Snowbunting yea I know it doesn't exist lol, I just put it there as temporary code. What I want to access is self.x of the human class, so that if the x coordinate of ANY alien and yes there will be multiple, collides it execute the print. What I effectively want to access is Human.self.x, which obviously doesnt work when ur calling it from another function.

Comment: In summary this is as clear as I can get. 
Conceptually: I want to access an instance variable defined in a certain class from some other class
My Case: I want to access the self.x instance variable defined in the Human Class from my Alien class
Why?: Since there will be multiple instances of self.x depending on which human spaceship, I can generalise it as a behaviour for all aliens.